# Mvc returns 403.14 instead of 404 from "hidden" folders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

We have a standard MVC4 web application, however the application has access to very confidential client data and so recently a 3rd party performed a security review.

Not a problem, we passed without any major issues however they pointed out we have a number of "Hidden Directories" which they have recommended we should return a status code 404 and not 403.14 (forbidden)

One of the folders is the default "Content" directory which contains images and other assets.

My question is how do I go about returning a 404 when /Content is requested?

Is this an IIS config or do I need to write something custom in the Mvc layer?

Comment: What are the reasons for returning 404? 403.14 is "Directory Listing Denied" which is perfect for this folder as you still need direct assess to the contents of it and it does exist. If you have confidential information in it then you should look at the design again

Comment: We don't have any confidential information stored in the these folders, it is only that the  security company have highlighted these and recommended they return a 404

Comment: Personally I wouldn't worry about it, I've worked on projects that have had outside sec companies look at it and not all of their recommendations were valid/made sense. If they haven't given a good enough reason for it then why give yourself more work? The fact is that url does exist, so a 404 would be wrong in this situation. Why would you 404 /Content but not /Content/someresource.js? NB. /Content isn't a hidden folder, it's just non-browsable.

Comment: It's the security scanning software, not the actual company, that is recommending the change. I'm getting the same thing right now, the software we are using is "IBM Security AppScan Standard 9.0.0.0"

Comment: BTW - I'm also trying to find how to return a 404 instead of a 403, if I find it, I'll link to it here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem. See the answer about adding the "NoAccessHandler" which inherits from IHttpHandler.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1478217.aspx?Make+IIS+return+a+404+status+code+instead+of+403

Edit: also, the httpHandlers config section needs added to the system.webServer section, NOT the system.web.